# Quit Modelsim from command line on error

Tags: tcl, command-line-arguments, modelsim

I am using a .do file which is used by GUI and by .tcl in command line (vsim -c) for simulating in Modelsim 10.3c

```
exec vsim -c -do DoFile.do
```

What I need is: 
If an error happens, modelsim should be quit and return to the `.tcl`. Otherwise it should simulate the project.

If I put the line `onerror { quit -f }` in my `.do` file the GUI is quit at the first error. So, this is not comfortable.

I didn't manage to use `onerror` (`warning: onerror command for use within macro`) or `$error` (unknown variable) inside tcl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a work around. I create a file in the .tcl and put the following lines into the .do scripts:

```
if [file exists ../Command_Line_Enable.txt] {
     onerror { quit -f }
}
```

So, if that file is not generated the GUI will not exit.

Answer (score 3):

I would need further information about your DO and Tcl script but you can use try-catch on vcom (for compiling VHDL) or vlog (for compiling Verilog/SystemVerilog). 
Here a short a example how to use it:

```
# set variable for compile error
set comperror ""

# compile files
catch "vcom -quiet -93 -work work name.vhd" comperror
catch "vcom -quiet -93 -work work name2.vhd" comperror
# ... and futher files..
if [expr  {${comperror}!=""}] then {
  # quit modelsim or do anything else
} else {
   # do simulation or execute further commands
}
```

You can compile ALL files and if a error occurs you can quit it. If it's successful you can run your simulation.

Comment: your suggestion is good, but I have several files with plenty of `vcom` lines.

Comment: No, I have only one .tcl script that starts several simulations with a .do file for each simulation.